# How to properly register Redis Master and Slaves with ServiceStack Client Managers?

Tags: redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

When I provision a default Redis cluster on Google Compute Engine, there is one master and 2 read-only slaves and Redis Sentinel is running on each machine. Given the previous cluster I'd now like to use this in my ServiceStack Service, but the Sentinel setting has me stumped, typically I do something along the lines of :

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c =>
    new RedisManagerPool(container.Resolve<IAppSettings>().GetString("Redis:Master")));
var cacheClient = container.Resolve<IRedisClientsManager>().GetCacheClient();
container.Register(cacheClient);
```

So a couple of things are incomplete with this setup, how do I specify the master and 2 read-only slaves, and configure Sentinel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RedisSentinel support in [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) is available in the `RedisSentinel` class but as it's still being tested, it's not yet announced. You can find some info on how to use and configure a [RedisSentinel in this previous StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28133657/85785).

### Configuring a RedisSentinel

When using a Redis Sentinel, it's the redis sentinel external process that manages the individual master/slave connections so you would just need to configure the sentinel host and ignore the individual master/slave connections.

### Configuring a RedisClientManager

Alternatively if you're using a [Redis Client Manager](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#redis-client-managers) you would do the opposite, i.e. ignore the sentinels hosts and configure the Redis Client Managers with the master and slave hosts. Only the [PooledRedisClientManager](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#pooledredisclientmanager) supports configuring both read-write/master and read-only/slave hosts, e.g:

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(c => 
    new PooledRedisClientManager(redisReadWriteHosts, redisReadOnlyHosts) { 
        ConnectTimeout = 100,
        //...
    });
```